# Comando para sair do escopo de uma função (equivalente ao `break`)

Tags: c++, qt

Como posso criar um algoritmo em `C++` (utilizando `Qt`) para abortar o processamento dos códigos a seguir?

Tenho que validar muitas entradas diferentes e não quero ficar criando `if` `else` `if` `else`. Fica horrível de feio o código.

Exemplo, mas o IDE retorna erro no `break` :

```
if(!price()){
  QMessageBox ...erro preco;
  break; ///Termina o código. 
}
if(!date()){
  QMessageBox ...erro data;
  break; ///Termina o código. 
}

///insert etc...///


bool window::price(){
 true or false
}

bool window::date(){
 true or false
}
```

Comment: Não seria `return` onde é `break`? Você podia completar o código que você postou.

Comment: @Lucas Nunes: Não. porque está no construtor o if.

Comment: Você pode dar `return` em um construtor (em em funções `void`), não tem problema. Basta escrever `return;`.

Comment: Blz. Obrigado :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`break` só é válido para fazer o fluxo de execução sair de um laço (`for`, `while` ou `do`-`while`) ou de um `switch`-`case`.

Em funções você pode usar um `return`:

```
if (!price()) {
  QMessageBox( ... );
  return; 
}
if (!date()) {
  QMessageBox( ... );
  return; 
}

//Algoritmo principal
...
```

Esta é um padrão muito utilizado. Checar por condições especiais e eliminá-las o mais cedo possível deixa o código mais legível, pois elimina esses casos do algoritmo principal.

Outra alternativa é lançar uma exceção. Esta alternativa é particularmente mais interessante se o código em questão estiver no construtor de um objeto. Desta forma o objeto nunca é criado em um estado inválido;

```
//Construtor
Object(Arg1 a1, Arg2 a2) attrib1(a1), attrib2(a2) {
    if (!price()) {
        throw InvalidPrice();
    }
    if (!date()) {
        throw InvalidDate();
    }
    //Se chegou até aqui o objeto é válido, continua a inicialização dele
    ...
}
```

Usando o objeto:

```
try {
    Object obj(arg1, arg2);
    //Se passou do construtor, o objeto é 100% válido
    obj.use();
}
catch (InvalidPrice const &) {
    QMessageBox( ... ); //Avisa sobre preço inválido
}
catch (InvalidDate const &) {
    QMessageBox( ... ); //Avisa sobre data inválida
}
```

Comment: @C. E. Gesser  Blz. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.